# Detach function in javascript called from Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, dom, razor

After finding that the hidden attribute only works with html5 and latest browsers I might have found another way to hide content based on conditional statements.
I ran into a problem where the function in javascript does not seem to executed, in short it does not hide the first paragraph.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

   function DetachEmptyField(pattern) {
   $("#pattern").val(pattern);
   $(pattern).detach();
   }

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="hideMe">This is a paragraph, 1.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph, 2.</p>

<button>Remove paragraph 1</button>

@* Razor conditional statements to be added later here ... *@
<script type="text/javascript">DetachEmptyField("#hideMe");</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DetachEmptyField` function is not available in the global scope (it lives inside your `ready` callback) and therefore your call will not work. If you really want to call it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">DetachEmptyField("#hideMe");</script>
```

you will have to declare it in the global scope (be aware that this is a bad practice)

```
// global function
function DetachEmptyField(pattern) {
$("#pattern").val(pattern);
$(pattern).detach();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Anyway, if you just need to hide the element you can use css `"display: none"` or if you can check on the server side whether or not the element should be present on the page you can simply not include that paragraph in the response.

```
@if ( /*some condition that needs to be true in order to display the <p> */ ) {
  @: <p id="hideMe">This is a paragraph, 1.</p>
}
```